# Show ProgressDialog in onPreExecute but it appear and dismiss in onPostExecute at the same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to show a ProgressDialog when running a time consuming method using a private class which extends AsyncTask in an activity class. But the ProgressDialog  which is supposed to be appear in onPreExecute doesn't show up when onPreExecute. Instead of it, the ProgressDialog shows up and dismiss immediately after the time consuming method is done.

```
            public class ABC extends Activity {

            /*somewhere in ABC
                load = new Load();
                load.execute(a,b,c);
                int action = load.get();*/

            private class Load extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Integer>{ 

                    private ProgressDialog progDailog;

                    @Override
                    protected Integer doInBackground(Object... param) {
                        Log.v("!!!!!!Load!!!!!!!!!","doInBackground");
                        Object a = (Object) param[0];
                        int b = (Integer) param[1];
                        int c = (Integer) param[2];
                        return a.doSomething(b, c);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);            
                        progDailog.dismiss();
                        Log.v("!!!!!!Load!!!!!!!!!","onPostExecute");
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        Log.v("!!!!!!Load!!!!!!!!!","onPreExecute");
                        progDailog = new ProgressDialog(ABC.this); 
                        progDailog.setMessage("Loading..."); 
                        progDailog.show();
                    }


                }

            }
```

Below is the logcat:

```
05-03 00:38:49.202: V/!!!!!!Load!!!!!!!!!(14666): preExecute
05-03 00:38:49.202: D/ProgressBar(14666): setProgress = 0
05-03 00:38:49.202: D/ProgressBar(14666): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
05-03 00:38:49.202: D/ProgressBar(14666): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
05-03 00:38:49.232: V/!!!!!!Load!!!!!!!!!(14666): doInBackground
05-03 00:38:53.662: I/Choreographer(14666): Skipped 269 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-03 00:38:53.762: D/ProgressBar(14666): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
05-03 00:38:53.762: D/ProgressBar(14666): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
05-03 00:38:53.762: D/ProgressBar(14666): updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
05-03 00:38:53.762: D/ProgressBar(14666): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
05-03 00:38:53.772: V/!!!!!!Load!!!!!!!!!(14666): onPostExecute
```

Comment: If you see the progressbar onPreExecute must work. Could you show the output from the Log? The doInBackgroudn really does not do mutch and this will finish lightning fast.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the definition of `doSomeThing` method. Since the execution time for this method or the operation you are performing is very short. thats why it is disappearing instantly. But if you want to see dialog or conform is it working properly. you can sleep in `doInBackground` method.paste this code in your `doInBackground` method

```
try{
Thread.sleep(3000);
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

now you will see dialog for three seconds.

Comment: doInBackground method takes few second to execute but the ProgressDialog appears after the method is finished

Comment: can u post your logcat..?..so i can see the order in which log appears.

Comment: yes. The problem is what the logcat show is fine but the progressDialog doesn't show up when the logcat shows "!!!!!!Load!!!!!!!!!" "preExecute". I saw the progressDialog few seconds after onPreExecute but before onPostExecute.

Comment: are you using emulator.

Comment: tried put sleep code in pre execute. it doesn't work